# Generate aar or jar from Android library with Dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I have an android library project(A) that reference another library contain *.jar in 'libs' and maven center and library project(B). But after generating aar file(project A), the depended library project and *.jar are not bundled in the output aar file.

Is there a way to make gradle bundle all dependencies library in the output aar file?

This is my build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.weibo.common"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3@jar'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient-android:4.3.5@jar'
    compile project(':volley-library')
}
```

Comment: What you're trying to do is very strongly discouraged; you should let clients of your library manage their own dependencies, especially for common third-party libraries like these. This is especially important since you can't have more than one copy of a class in your build. If a dependent project had its own dependency on one of these libraries, the build would fail.

Comment: OK，i know how should i do. Thanks.